# Scala type inference rule over contravarience?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, type-inference, circe

I'm using Circe and noticed something that i am not so confortable with and would like to understand what is going on under the hood ?

Fundamentally it is not really a circe issue. Also i was just playing with circe around to test few thing. So could have decoded in `JsonObject` straight but that is beside the point.

```
val jobjectStr = """{
    |    "idProperty": 1991264,
    |    "nIndex": 0,
    |    "sPropertyValue": "0165-5728"
    |  }""".stripMargin



val jobject = decode[Json](jobjectStr).flatMap{ json =>
    json.as[JsonObject]
}
```

My issue is with the flapMap signature of Either, contravariance and what is happening here:

We have the following types:

```
decode[Json](jobjectStr): Either[Error, Json]
```

```
json.as[JsonObject]: Decoder.Result[JsonObject]
```

where circe defines

```
final type Result[A] = Either[DecodingFailure, A]
```

and

```
sealed abstract class DecodingFailure(val message: String) extends Error {
```

Now the signature of flatMap in either is:

```
def flatMap[A1 >: A, B1](f: B => Either[A1, B1]): Either[A1, B1]
```

In other words, talking only about type it is like my code is doing

```
Either[Error, Json] flatMap Either[DecodingFailure, JsonObject]
```

**Hence my issue is:** `DecodingFailure >: Error` **is not true**

And Indeed the type of the full expression is:

```
decode[Json](jobjectStr).flatMap{ json =>
    json.as[JsonObject]
}: Either[Error, JsonObject]
```

Hence i'm confused, because my understanding is that the type of the first Parameter of Either is Contravariant in the flatMap Signature. Here there seems to be some wierd least upper bound inferencing going on ... But i am not sure why or if it is even the case.

Any explanation ?

Comment: First of all **Either** is _covariant_ on both of their type arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first of all, we need to understand that the compiler will always try to infer types that allow compilation. The only real way to avoid something to compile is to use **implicits**.
*(not sure if this is part of the language specification, or a compiler implementation detail, or something common to all compilers, or a bug or a feature)*.

Now, let's start with a simpler example **List** and `::`.

```
sealed trait List[+A] {
  def ::[B >: A](b: B): List[B] = Cons(b, this)
}

final case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
final case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
```

So, assuming the compiler will always allow some code like `x :: list` will always compile. Then, we have three scenarios:

1. `x` is of type **A** and `list` is a **List[A]**, so it is obvious that the returned value has to be of type **List[A]**.
2. `x` is of some type **C** and `list` is a **List[A]**, and  **C** is a subtype of **A** *(`C <: A`)*. Then, the compiler simply upcast `x` to be of type **A** and the process continues as the previous one.
3. `x` is of some type **D** and `list` is a **List[A]**, and **D** is not a subtype of **A**. Then, the compiler finds a new type **B** which is the LUB between **D** and **A**, the compiler finally upcast both `x` to be of type **B** and `list` to be a **List[B]** *(this is possible due covariance)* and proceeds like the first one.
   Also, note that due to the existence of types like **Any** and **Nothing** there is "always" a LUB between two types.

Now let's see **Either** and `flatMap`.

```
sealed trait Either[+L, +R] {
  def flatMap[LL >: L, RR](f: R => Either[LL, RR]): Either[LL, RR]
}

final case class Left[+L](l: L) extends Either[L, Nothing]
final case clas Right[+R](r: R) extends Either[Nothing, R]
```

Now, assuming my left side is an **Error**, I feel this behaviour of returning the LUB between the two possible lefts is the best, since at the end I would have the first error, or the second error or the final value, so since I do not know which of the two errors it was then that error must be of some type that encapsulates both possible errors.

Comment: Very on point explanation! Many thanks. This being I did some research in the mean time and in the book: Programming scala, 2nd, the author mention that at least in scala 2.11 u would get a warning for the upcast! Sounds like scala 2.12 removed it and the only way to enforce what you want is to firmly declare the type to bloc undesirable inferencing. By any chance any idea why this warning was removed ?

Comment: Not sure, I also do not remember such warning. There is one if the inferred type is **Any** since inferring **Any** is probably always an error. But any other type is most of the time ok, also if it is not a good type, you would get another compilation error somewhere.

Comment: From the Book: ```While convenient, inferring a broader, LUB type can be a surprise if you thought you were not changing from the original type parameter. That’s why Scala 2.11 added a warning when an expression infers a broad LUB type.```

Comment: That would be 2.11. I don't see that in 2.12. or 2.13
```scala> 0.1 +: Seq(2, 3)
<console>:9: warning: a type was inferred to be `AnyVal`; this may
  indicate a programming error.
              0.1 +: res0
                  ^
res1: Seq[AnyVal] = List(0.1, 1, 2, 3)```

Comment: Ah yeah that is the one I mentions, it only warns for things like **Any**. That is behind a flag, if you use something like `sbt-tpolecat` you would get all those flags turned on by default and turn all warnings into errors.

Comment: I see i am on the console right now. Will need to find which scalac option to turn up. Thanks for the help

Comment: Seems like that would be `-Xlint:infer-any`

Answer (score 3):

This really isn't a variance issue. `A1 >: A` is just telling us that the result type, `A1`, might have to be a super-type of the received type, `A`, if the compiler has to go looking for a least upper bound (the LUB). (The use of `A1` in the `f: B => ...` description is, I think, a bit confusing.)

Consider the following:

```
class Base
class SubA extends Base
class SubB extends Base

Either.cond(true, "a string", new SubA)
  .flatMap(Either.cond(true, _, new SubB))

//res0: scala.util.Either[Base,String] = Right(a string)
```

Notice how the result is `Either[Base,String]` because `Base` is the LUB of `SubA` and `SubB`.

Comment: The notion of super type should make sense however because if you fail from the start, you do not want someone at the end to call function on a failure of a subtype. So I guess it make sense. What I don’t understand is the rule applied and infer the least upper bound ! In other words, when does the LUB rules applies

Comment: Said differently: When does the LUB apply vs an error is thrown. For instance i just notice that the same thing is for scala SeqLike prepend: ```def +:[B >: A, That](elem: B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That =``` Clearly B is contravariant. But here the LUB will apply.

Comment: Sounds like one first comment could be that, ```def +:[B >: A, That]`` is usually found in container that are covariant in their Type Parameter, they need that to be able to have method that consume their Type Parameter, because method parameter are always contravariant. FunctionN is simply contravariant in the Type Parameters, so no inference will happen. However SeqLike, is Convariant in the Type Parameter, so this kind of method is necessary, and the compiler might have to resort to LUB inference. That the only inference i am able to draw so far :)

Comment: Now why does the scala commpiler allow LUB in Co-Variant Container where a method type Parameter is ConTravariant, vs in Container that are simply contravariant in their type parameter, would be my million dollar question at this point :)